# TwinCAT 3 visualize FTP Server

Tags: ftp, plc, twincat

Is there any way to visualize the connection (and download a file) from a FTP server?
All this in TwinCAT 3.

I am trying to download a file from a FTP server. However I can't seem to find a correct visualisation.

I found a demo code on the site of Beckhoff where they download a file from a server, but this is meant for an actual PLC.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

By utilizing [TF6300](https://www.beckhoff.com/english.asp?twincat/tf6300.htm), you can implement a FTP-client using TwinCAT3. For download of a file from an FTP-server, Beckhoff has a good [example here](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6300_tc3_ftp/82967307.html&id=2270930954326856405) for an implementation of a file download. This is possible to do with any ADS-capable device, for instance TwinCAT3. You can install this on your PC, it doesn't need to an actual PLC. To visualize this, I'd just go along and visualize some of the variables that are instantiated when you instantiate the function blocks that you need for the required functionality. If you for instance instantiate the FB "FB_FTP_FileDownload", you have access to the output variable "nProgress", which shows the current status of the data transmission in percent. Regarding the visualization, there are many ways to do it. You can for example:
- Implement this directly with a TwinCAT3 visu (using ADS as middleware)
- Use adslib.dll (or any other ads implementation) for your own HMI
- Use any other middleware (OPC-UA) and publish your data to your HMI

The outputs from the function blocks required for a file-download (FB_FTP_Open, FB_FTP_FileDownload, FB_FTP_Close) will give you all the information that you need to show the status of a download.